# QUICKBLOX UNABLE TO SEND PUSH NOTIFICATION ON CHAT

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

{"errors":{"base":["APNS (Apple Push) is not enabled for this application. Please upload proper push certificate in the Push Notifications module, Settings tab in admin panel.","No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for 'apns' (through SDK or REST API)"]}}

Answer (score 0):

To make the push notifications work within iOS platform with QuickBlox, you first need to create an APNS certificate and then upload it to your QuickBlox dashboard.

Please check a [detailed insctruction](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/ios-push-notifications) in the QuickBlox documentation.